# How do I disable Windows Error Reporting in Win 10 Pro using Group Policy Editor?

Tags: windows-10, windows-error-reporting, gpedit

I'm running Win 10 Pro v 1607.

I was looking at a thread here on turning off Error Reporting, and someone mentioned that it is possible through gpedit.msc in Win 10 Pro.

[Disable Error Reporting In Windows 10 Home](https://superuser.com/questions/950997/disable-error-reporting-in-windows-10-home)

Others mentioned a Reg hack, but if there's a way to do it natively in Win 10 Pro I'd prefer to do that.

When I open gpedit.msc I'm not sure where to go in the sub menu to do it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: FYI... I think there is an **Windows Error Reporting Service** named service in services.msc that could be stopped and set to disabled that may do this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I saw on this [source](https://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/enable-or-disable-windows-error-reporting-in-windows-10/) (*warning: very ad heavy page*) and from reading some of the setting descriptions as I saw them within GPEDIT, the areas you want to look at are

- the **Turn off Windows Error Reporting** policy setting in **Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Internet Communication Management/Internet Communication settings**
- the **Disable Windows Error Reporting** policy setting in **Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Error Reporting**

Also, as said in comments, just disabling the WER service will accomplish your goal as well.